# how to use an angular translationfilter inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have set up a translateProvider as follows:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider){
        $translateProvider.translations('en', {
             'HELLO' : 'Hello'
        });
        $translateProvider.translation('de', {
             'HELLO' : 'Hallo'
        });
        $translateProvider.prefferedLanguage('en');
 }])
```

and I can translate strings in HTML using expression with the filter successfully like:

```
{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}
```

shows up 'Hello' (or 'Hallo' depending on the preferred language setup).

How can I use that filter now in Javascript, let's say, in a controller?

My current approach is not working:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ExampleController', [ '$scope', '$translate'], function($scope, $translate){
        $scope.obj = {
             translatedString = $translate('HELLO')
        };
    });
```

as it shows up  [object Object] instead the translation for 'HELLO'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$translate is asynchronous and it returns promise instead of translated string so it can be used like this:

```
$translate('HEADLINE_TEXT').then(function (translation) {
  $scope.translatedText = translation;
});
```

More info https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate

Comment: its working. thanks. I also achieved the goal using translatedString = $translate.instant('HELLO');